# Is this regex illegal "a(b|)c"?

Tags: regex

I wrote a program which can generate regex like this `a(b|)c`. Actually, it means `(abc)|(ac)`. But is `a(b|)c` an acceptable regex for any regex engine? Or is there any other alternative to give the same semantic meaning?

Further question: is there any tool can covert it to a "normal" representation? e.g convert `a(b|(c|))d` to `a(b|(c)?)d`

Comment: It's acceptable, just that it is weird to write like this.

Comment: It won't necessarily work for _any_ regex engine, but it will for the common Perl-like flavour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ab?c`, or `ab{0,1}c` would make more sense. An `a`, followed by at most one `b`, followed by a `c`.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't illegal, but it's an extremely odd formation.  `?` is more "idiomatic" for the purpose (by which I mean it will be clearer to and more readily understood by "speakers" of regex).

Comment: But as the OP stated, _"I wrote a program which can generate regex"_. This isn't about writing idiomatic regex, it's about whether or not the regex generated procedurally will **work**. No -1, however, since you correctly stated that it is not illegal.

Comment: @Phrogz: Doesn't necessarily follow.  His program may be generating regex that will later be maintained by humans, in which case idiom is significant.

Comment: A technically valid point (though I personally consider that case to be so unlikely that I do not consider it valid by default, without the OP stating so :)

Comment: @Phrogz: That is certainly your privilege, sir. :)

Answer (score 2):

use this regular expression`ab?c`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a valid regular expression. Proof in Ruby:

```rb
irb(main):003:0> "fooacbar".match( /a(b|)c/ )
#=> #<MatchData "ac" 1:"">
irb(main):004:0> "fooabcbar".match( /a(b|)c/ )
#=> #<MatchData "abc" 1:"b">
```

Proof in JavaScript:

```js
console.log( "fooabcbar".match(/a(b|)c/) )
//-> ["abc", "b"]

console.log( "fooacbar".match(/a(b|)c/) )
//-> ["ac", ""]
```

As others have shown, however, it is more idiomatic to write:

```
/ab?c/     # If you have just one character optional
/a(foo)?c/ # If you have an arbitrary string optional
```

Also note that many regex engines allow you specify that the parentheses are non-capturing (which may provide slight performance benefits):

```
/a(?:foo)?c/ # Optional arbitrary string that you don't need to save
```